# WifiDirect .discoverPeers is often BUSY or in ERROR

Tags: android, wifi-direct

```
manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Toast.makeText(WiFiDirectActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Sometimes it works just fine, other times it will spend over a half hour erroring out each time I click my button to discover peers.   I will get BUSY (2) and ERROR (0) results at about the same rate.

I haven't been able to find out WHY I would ever get these results, and if I just have to live with them. My Tablets are a Nexus 7 running Android 4.3.

Questions:

Can I expect other devices to be just as flaky?
 Is there anything I can do to improve their behavior?
 Can I do anything to figure out more details than "BUSY" or "ERROR"?  LOGCAT doesn't seem to help...

Edit:  I meant I have two tablets, both of which are Nexus 7s.

Comment: A Nexus 7 will not do for wifi direct. You need at least two devices. Which one will you blame?

Comment: Ah, good catch. I meant I had two identical Nexus 7 tablets.  Both are having the same problem (just not always at the same time).  So it takes a while for BOTH of them to be cooperating enough to connect.

Comment: I have tested mainly with 3 devices: HTC One X+ / Galaxy Note4 / Nexus7. When I test my app with HTC and Note4 I have less trouble than when I test a device with the Nexus7. But the full process of discovering is kind of rocket science... We have to fine tune with a lot of trial and errors...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?